# For loop not running in method

Tags: java, android, for-loop, return, switch-statement

For some reason my for loop is not running and I can't seem to figure out why. It keeps skipping straight to the return statement. Thanks.

```
 public char[] palindromeCheck(char[] original) {

    char[] reversed = new char[original.length];

    for (int i = original.length; i <0; i--) {
        switch (original[i]){
            case 'A':
                original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                break;
            case 'E':
                original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                break;
            case 'I':
                original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                break;
            case 'O':
                original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                break;
            case 'U':
                original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                break;
            default:
                original[i] = Character.toUpperCase(original[i]);
                break;
        }
        reversed[i] = original[i];
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: You have several answers. If one of them solved your issue then mark it as accepted. This will help you get faster responses to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = original.length; i <0; i--)
```

The condition is always false since a length is always >= 0. Since you're indexing an array, you probably want to loop from length-1 to 0 like

```
for (int i = original.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for (int i = original.length; i <0; i--) {
```

to:

```
for (int i = original.length; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Otherwise it just doesn't enter the loop, since the length is bigger than zero and the condition will always evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for (int i = original.length; i < 0; i--) {
```

to:

```
for (int i = original.length; i >= 0; i--) {
```

The other posts are correctly addressing the issue, but changing your condition so the loop will not reach 0. If you want to reach 0, use `>=` as above.

Comment: @rgettman Now everybody is editing their answer to add `=` without even giving credits. You're the only one who did ;)

Comment: Well, we (and everyone who takes a look at the [revision history for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22307114/timeline)) know that you had it right from the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

probably you have written wrong condition in for loop which will always false

```
for (int i = original.length; i <0; i--)
```

a length is always >= 0. I think you should write `i > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop had the ending expression reversed.

```
public char[] palindromeCheck(char[] original) {

    char[] reversed = new char[original.length];

        for (int i = original.length; i>0; i--) {
            switch (original[i]){
                case 'A':
                    original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                    break;
                case 'O':
                    original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    original[i] = Character.toLowerCase(original[i]);
                    break;
                default:
                    original[i] = Character.toUpperCase(original[i]);
                    break;
            }
            reversed[i] = original[i];
        }

        return reversed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful, when you write the conditions in the For Loop. 
The code below works for your case.

```
 for (int i = original.length; i >0; i--) {
//Your code
}
```

In future, while you are in debug mode. Learn how to identify these mistakes.In this case you will notice, that the control directly jumps out of the for loop and analyze each single conditions inside the loop.